# What is the use of hit api in async task?

Tags: android

**Can we use Httpget/Httppost without async??**

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
```

if i was using without async, it gives the threat error.

Comment: read this document http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: You cant do it in gui thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Exception occurs due to the any heavy task performed on the main thread. If that performing task takes too much time it may comes to an error.To handle this we have to use a extra Thread to run this type of code.
There is no need of run the code inside AsyncTask but the network operation should inside a thread like this.But AsyncTask is a better option for this type of operations so everybody suggest that.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your code goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Also you can change the default behavior using the following

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the interaction may take a long time to get an answer, you can not use the main thread because that's how you stop the activity of the application (all operations synchronous) and if that does happen you will receive ANR.
Therefore any action that takes time set for background thread, if you want the background thread after he finish to process the data can transfer information to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, Ideally you should not do Network operations on Main thread, Since this will make the UI unusable till the network operation is done, so in turn will lead to Application not responding errors. 
But if you still need it you can always disable Strictmode using

```
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX);
```